# Batch File issue: "1 was unexpected at this time"

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I am new to this and unsure how to fix the code.

I typed in:

> ```bash
> >for /1 %f in  (1,1,10) do (copy "cover og" "File_copy_%f.xlsx"
> /1 was unexpected at this time.
>
> >for %f in (1,1,10) do (copy "cover og" "File_copy_%f.xlsx"
> More? copy "cover og"
> More? Copy file "cover og"
> ```

I was trying to follow YouTube and looked online.
I tried taking out the `/1` but received the question `"More?"`.

Could anyone explain what's wrong with the code and why `"More?"` was asked?

Comment: did you mistype `for /L` as `for /1`? https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html

Answer (score 1):

#### "1 was unexpected at this time"

You should be using `for /L (the letter L not the number 1):

```
for /L %f in  (1,1,10) do (copy "cover og" "File_copy_%f.xlsx"
```

> `FOR /L`
>
> Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers.
>
> Syntax
> `FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command`

Source: [For - Loop through a range of numbers - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

```bat
Your code has 2 syntax errors:

    /1 not a valid command complement 
    ⇈
    ⇵              opened (here and ...      didn't close here)
    ⇊                     ⇊                                  ⇊  
for /1 %f in  (1,1,10) do (copy "cover og" "File_copy_%f.xlsx"
```

**1.** You see, **`/1`** is without reference to interpreting the command syntax, with no valid option/complement to any for loop, and possible uses of the `for /Loop` are:

- in ***UPPERCASE*** for better visualization!

```bat
/L      FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command 

/F      FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command 
        FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ("Text string to process") DO command

/R      FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command/R

/D      FOR /D [/r] %%parameter IN (folder_set) DO command

/D /R   The option /D /R is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,   
        while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will 
        only match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames).
```

> ```bat
> > for /1 %f in (1,1,10) do (copy "cover og" "File_copy_%f.xlsx"
> /1 was unexpected at this time.
> ```

---

**2.** You opened a block `(command)` and didn't close it, so the command interpreter is asking you **`More?`**, **`More?`** until you close with "`)`", then he will stops asking and executes your command...

> ```bat
>             you opened "(" here    and      didn't close here ")"
>                         ⇅                                      ⇅
> > for %f in (1,1,10) do (copy "cover og"  "File_copy_%f.xlsx" More?
>
> More? copy "cover og"
> More? Copy file "cover og"
> ```

---

As it seems to me in your code what would suit you would be:

```bat
for /L %L in (1,1,10) do copy "cover og" "File_copy_%~L.xlsx"
```

---

- Some further reading:
- **[`For /?` Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
- **[`For /F` Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  - **[`For /F` commands](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.htm)**
- **[`For /D` Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**
- **[`For /R` Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**
- **[How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)**